# Какие есть неопределенные сочетания клавиш в vim? Как создать отдельный режим в vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc

Я переназначила клавиши стрелок для динамического изменения пропорций окон:

```
map <Left> <C-W><
map <Right> <C-W>>
map <Up> <C-W>-
map <Down> <C-W>+
```

Тем не менее я не хочу использовать клавиши стрелок при работе с редактором, из-за чего возник вопрос: какие сочетания символьных и модальных клавиш не определены в редакторе? Например, clrl + ?, чтобы можно было на такое сочетание определить изменение ширины окна, например
Или же создать отдельный режим в редакторе (как это сделано в ['vim-swap'](https://github.com/machakann/vim-swap.git), например), в котором можно изменять пропорции окна путем зажатия различных клавиш

Comment: `:h index`. Но, может быть, лучше сначала освоить инструмент, а не тащить в него свои привычки и не городить велосипеды?